# How to show prices below a certain number?

Tags: python, django

I made filtration on my website. There are two options. Either to show prices, which are above "min_price" field or to show prices which are below "max_price" (you can choose both). The problem is that "max_price" shows "min_price" and I don't know why.

my forms.py code

```
class ProductSort(forms.Form):
    min_price = forms.IntegerField(label='от', required = False)
    max_price = forms.IntegerField(label='до', required = False)
```

my views.py code (shows choosing options)

```
form = ProductSort(request.GET)
if form.is_valid():
    if form.cleaned_data["min_price"]:
        products = products.filter(price__gte=form.cleaned_data["min_price"])
    if form.cleaned_data["max_price"]:
        products = products.filter(price__gte=form.cleaned_data["max_price"])
```

Comment: `price__lte`, perhaps?

Comment: Now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is a bit off, the filter should check for `price`s that are greater or equal to (`__gte`) the given minimum price, and less than or equal to ([**`__lte`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#lte)) than the given maximum price, so:

```
form = ProductSort(request.GET)
if form.is_valid():
    if form.cleaned_data["min_price"]:
        products = products.filter(price__gte=form.cleaned_data["min_price"])
    if form.cleaned_data["max_price"]:
        # __lte instead of __gte
        products = products.filter(price__lte=form.cleaned_data["max_price"])
```